# Prevent AddRedirectToWwwPermanent() from adding "www" to the front of *.azurewebsites.net in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

When I deploy my website as a Azure Web App, my `AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()` rewrite rule is adding "www." to the front of the default azure URL, e.g. `www.myproject.azurewebsites.net`. Using "www" with the subdomain, causes the page not to load.

Is there a way to skip the `AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()` rewrite rule specifically for the `*.azurewebsites.net` URL?

I'm currently using the Rewriter in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
);
```

Alternatively, is there a way to redirect the `*.azurewebsites.net` URL to my own custom domain? I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect(@"myproject.azurewebsites.net", @"www.example.com", StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently)
    .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
);
```

Update, also tried:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirect(@"https://myproject.azurewebsites.net", @"https://www.example.com", StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently)
        .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
    );
```

Comment: Try adding `http://` or `https://` to your URLs

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't make a difference. Does AddRedirect() take into account the domain name part of the URL? All of the examples I've seen that use it just deal with redirecting the path portion of the URL.

Comment: You setup custom domains in the Azure portal.  You'll need a CNAME DNS record to point your domain to the Azure domain.

Comment: Even with custom domains set in the Azure portal, people can still access the default `*.azurewebsites.net` domain. Or am I missing something in the Azure portal setup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my solution, which works in `ASP.NET Core 2.1`. However, I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do the redirect, so I'm open to better suggestions.

Since I couldn't get the built in `AddRedirect()` rule to work (I still think I may have just been using it wrong), I created a custom rewrite rule to do the redirect.

Here's my `RedirectAzureWebsitesRule`, which redirects `*.azurewebsites.net` to the custom domain:

```
public class RedirectAzureWebsitesRule : IRule
{
    public int StatusCode { get; } = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        HostString host = context.HttpContext.Request.Host;

        if (host.HasValue && host.Value == "my-project.azurewebsites.net")
        {
            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = request.Scheme + "://" + "www.example.com" + request.PathBase + request.Path + request.QueryString;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs`, I called the new rule, before `AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()`:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .Add(new RedirectAzureWebsitesRule())
    .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. STACK OVERFLOW, STOP DOWNVOTING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS

Comment: Works thank you. While we are at it, also force https: .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()  And remove trailing slash: .AddRedirect("(.*)/$", "$1", StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently)

Comment: It should be noted that this is only for `ASP.NET Core 2.1` and as of `ASP.NET Core 3.0`, they added an overload to the `AddRedirectToWwwPermanent` to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a slight variation to Wellspring's answer. If you want to keep the `azurewebsites.net` domain running still you could do the following:

```
public class RedirectAzureWebsitesRule : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        HostString host = context.HttpContext.Request.Host;

        if (host.HasValue && host.Value.ToLower().Contains(".azurewebsites.net"))
        {
            //if we are viewing on azure's domain - skip the www redirect
            context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure you can run on both domains (if you have a need to):

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .Add(new RedirectAzureWebsitesRule())
    .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could **add a redirect rule to your site**’s `web.config` file. You can do that by adding the following rewrite rule to the `web.config` file in your `wwwroot` folder. If you don’t have a `web.config` file, then you can create one and just paste the text below into it, just change the host names to match your site’s host names:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://zainrizvi.io/blog/block-default-azure-websites-domain/).

You could could achieve this by **Mapping an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps**,  here is the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: I created the `web.config` file in the wwwroot folder (changing the hostnames) and published it to Azure, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Are you sure this works with `ASP.NET Core 2.1`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.AddRedirect(@"^https?://(.+)\.azurewebsites.net(.*)$", @"https://$1.com$2", StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @tj-cappelletti pointed out in a comment, there is a new overload that makes this easy.

```
app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent("myproject.com"));
```

This will redirect requests to "myproject.com" to "www.myproject.com", but will leave anything else (including "*.azurewebsites.net") alone. You can even specify a list of domains instead of just one.

*While you are testing this, don't forget that these are "permanent" redirects, so your browser will cache them. Open your browser's dev tools, go to the network tab, and check the `Disable Cache` box. Now, when you visit one of these, you get the current redirect output. If you don't do this, it may look like the desired redirect is "still wrong" when you've actually fixed it and just have old data.*

Comment: Very important note with cache! Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this:

```
.AddRedirect("^your-site.azurewebsites.net$", "https://www.Your-Site.com/{R:0}", StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently)
```

Comment: I don't think this works. But would be nice if we could do something similar to this. So if someone could confirm please, thanks.